# Why does trait implementation for Box<T> conflict with Fn()?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

A simplistic program to demonstrate this behavior:

```
use std::boxed::Box;

struct Cow;

trait CanSpeak {
    fn speak(&self);
}

impl CanSpeak for Cow {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("moo");
    }
}

impl<F: Fn()> CanSpeak for F {
    fn speak(&self) {
        self();
    }
}

impl<T: CanSpeak> CanSpeak for Box<T> {
    fn speak(&self) {
        (**self).speak()
    }
}

fn lol_speak() {
    println!("lol")
}

fn lets_speak<T: CanSpeak>(t: & T) {
    t.speak();
}

fn main() {
    let cow = Cow;
    lets_speak( &cow );

    lets_speak( &lol_speak );

    let boxed_cow = Box::new(Cow);
    lets_speak( &boxed_cow );
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
test.rs:15:1: 19:2 error: conflicting implementations for trait `CanSpeak` [E0119]
test.rs:15 impl<F: Fn()> CanSpeak for F {
test.rs:16     fn speak(&self) {
test.rs:17         self();
test.rs:18     }
test.rs:19 }
test.rs:15:1: 19:2 help: run `rustc --explain E0119` to see a detailed explanation
test.rs:21:1: 25:2 note: note conflicting implementation here
test.rs:21 impl<T: CanSpeak> CanSpeak for Box<T> {
test.rs:22     fn speak(&self) {
test.rs:23         (**self).speak()
test.rs:24     }
test.rs:25 }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

My questions are:

1. [As far as I can tell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) `Box<T>` does not implement `Fn()` trait. Then why does above example fail?
2. What is the correct implementation for what I'm trying to do?

I've just started learning Rust. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

The two do conflict, because it is *possible* for a type `Box<T>` to have `T` implementing `CanSpeak` and `Box<T>` implementing `Fn()`. Rust coherence rules aren’t about what *is* but what *can be*.

Here’s an example of implementing `Fn()` for `Box<Cow>`, which would clearly explode things if it allowed your two generic trait implementations:

```
// (This attribute on the crate.)
#![feature(unboxed_closures, core)]

impl Fn<()> for Box<Cow> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, _: ()) { }
}

impl FnMut<()> for Box<Cow> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _: ()) { }
}

impl FnOnce<()> for Box<Cow> {
    type Output = ();
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _: ()) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply, but I'm afraid I still did not get it. Can you explain what makes `Box` special in this case that Rust thinks it can conflict? For example If, I understand your explanation correctly, any container, lets say `Arc<T>` should also conflict because `T` can implement `CanSpeak` and `Arc<T>` can implement `Fn()`. But Replacing `Box` in my example with `Arc` works just fine.

Comment: There is *nothing* special about it. It’s just that you’ve provided two generic implementations for a trait which can overlap.

Comment: Then why does `Arc` work? In my example if I replace `Box` with `Arc` it compiles without any errors.

Comment: Box is special, it's marked `#[fundamental]` (and Arc is not). What the exact rules are, I don't know off hand.

Comment: I'm with Vikas - this evidently isn't the right answer for any type but `Box`.

Comment: `#[fundamental]` is specified in this [coherence RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/8e2d3a3341da533f846f61f10335b72c9a9f4740/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md)

Comment: Oh no, the next piece of the puzzle: the `Fn` trait is marked `#[fundamental]` too, it's special too! A right thicket! Use a different bound, and it will conflict.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan you are suggesting there is no special treatment for `Box`, but that logic conflicts with why `Arc` works. @bluss if you think it is because `Box` is special, feel free to add another answer.

Comment: The #[fundamental] on both the Fn trait and on Box play a role.